# Why must use reference in ranged-based for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I was stuck in a piece of code in C++ Primer and had thought about it more than 1 hour. The code is

```
for (auto row : ia)//should use &row here
   for (auto col : row)
```

The explanation for it is

> We do so in order to avoid the normal array to pointer conversion. Because row is not a reference, when the compiler
>   initializes row it will convert each array element (like any other object of array type)
>   to a pointer to that array’s first element. As a result, in this loop the type of row is
>   int*. The inner for loop is illegal. Despite our intentions, that loop attempts to
>   iterate over an int*.

I know it has something to do with iterations each time doing `for(auto col:row)`. What I can't understand about

> We do so in order to avoid the normal array to pointer conversion"

is what's the form of "ia" we passed in for the outer loop? Should it be a pointer that points to the address of its first element rather than a "concrete" array? Then what's wrong for the inner loop? I thought it should be the same mechanism with the outer loop.. I can't understand the posts on Q&A. Someone please enlighten me please...What's wrong with my understanding...A good link is also welcomed! Many thanks in advance!

The declaration for ia is

```
constexpr size_t rowCnt = 3, colCnt = 4;
int ia[rowCnt][colCnt]; // 12 uninitialized elements
// for each row
  for (size_t i = 0; i != rowCnt; ++i) {
// for each column within the row
    for (size_t j = 0; j != colCnt; ++j) {
// assign the element's positional index as its value
        ia[i][j] = i * colCnt + j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a range-based for loop declared as:

```
 for ( decl : coll ) {
 statement }
```

is equivalent to the following, if coll provides begin() and end() members:

```
    for (auto _pos=coll.begin(), _end=coll.end(); _pos!=_end; ++_pos ) 
   {  
      decl = *_pos; 
       statement 
    }
```

or, if that doesn’t match, to the following by using a global begin() and end() taking coll as argument:

```
for (auto _pos=begin(coll), _end=end(coll); _pos!=_end; ++_pos )
 { 
    decl = *_pos; 
    statement 
 }
```

Now look at the line `decl = *_pos;` , here each time compiler will initialize dec ,  it will convert each array element (like any other object of array type) to a pointer to that array’s first element .

In your case , type of raw will comes out to be int* on which next for loop can't work and hence it becomes illegal .

Comment: Thanks! I think your explanation is the easiest one for me to understand.n

Comment: Correct in spirit, but the equivalent code first evaluates the container expression: auto && coll_expr = coll;. Thereafter using coll_expr. This makes ranged base for work well with e.g. functions returning a vector.

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks for pointing this out! Although I currently can't understand what you are talking about.. But I got what I want easily from his example illustration so I accepted his answer. Later when I finished this book probably I will understand all those things! Thanks for all the efforts!

Answer (score 4):

Range-based for loops are based on the `begin` and `end` functions which don't work on `T*` but work on `T[N]`.

The implementation for:

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

is along the lines of:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
        __end = end_expr; 
        __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

Since in the outer for loop the array would decay to a pointer with `auto row`, the inner for loop would become illegal.

Answer (score 2):

`Range based for` loop works for either with `array type` or `user defined type` having member functions `begin` and `end`.

By `array-to-pointer decay rule` when you pass `array` to a function which takes a `pointer`, then the array decay to pointer
But when you use a template by `**reference**` then template type is deduced as a `array type`:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&);

int main() {
    int ia[2][2] = {{0,1}, {2,3}};

    auto row_val = ia[0]; //int*
    auto& row_ref = ia[0]; //int [2]

    foo(row_val); //void foo<int*>(int*&)
    foo(row_ref); //void foo<int [2]>(int (&) [2])      
}
```

Here you can see that (from the error it creates!!) that type deduced for `row_val` and `row_ref` are not same

```
row_val ==> int*
row_ref ==> int [2]
```

You have to use `for(auto& row: ia)` as `row` will now `array type` not a `pointer`. hence you can use the inner loop  `for (auto col : row)`.